# eclipse, maven, Add Dependency is not working

Tags: eclipse, maven

I created a java project in eclipse, maven2 is already installed in eclipse, I enabled Maven dependency management for this project, but when I want to do "Add dependency" by typping cxf , it keep searching for a while then I got this :

Search error: Search error

Comment: Which version of Eclipse, Which of the Eclipse Plugin for Maven and furthermore are you sitting behind a proxy ?

Comment: version of Eclipse : Version: Indigo ,  maven was from Sonatype, I am using my computer at home I don't think I am behind a proxy, how to know if you are behind a proxy ?   Thanks

Comment: The home of Maven is Apache not Sonatype ;-) http://maven.apache.org/ Are you using a kind of a repository manager like nexus ?

Comment: When I wanted to add Maven plugin, I went to Add Software and I typped in the URL : http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that works for me.

**Solution**: In the project that is not building correctly, right-click on the project and choose `Properties`, and then `Mave`n. Uncheck the box labeled `Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects`, hit `Apply`, and then `OK`. Right-click again on your project and do a `Maven->Update Snapshots` (or Update Dependencies) and your errors should go away when your project rebuilds (automatically if you have auto-build enabled).

Comment: You should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65363/can-i-answer-my-own-question). Click the hollow green checkmark to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had like this probleme if after making that solution guys tell you and your **add dependency** doesn't find make this.
Right click your project and **propoties** go to **maven** and uncheck **Resolve dependencies from workspace project** restar your IDE
if it doesn't come do this 
In **window** --> **show view** --> click **Other** after add **maven repositories** and add it after go to **global ripositories**--> right click on **central(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2l)** and click **Rebuild index** it will take many time but wait and after done **restar** your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that works for me.

In the project that is not building correctly, right-click on the project and choose Properties, and then Maven.

Uncheck the box labeled "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects", hit Apply, and then OK.

Right-click again on your project and do a Maven->Update Snapshots (or Update Dependencies) and your errors should go away when your project rebuilds (automatically if you have auto-build enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue . It was resolved using performing the above step and using the regular expression in the highlighted box.
[image]